# wp_get_attachment_image_src returns incorrect URL on multisite

Tags: multisite, images

I'm not sure how much code to post because I don't think too much is relevant.  I'm just dumping the contents of `wp_get_attachment_image_src` and the contents turn out to be incorrect on multisite.

```
$id = 1290; // tested with a random ID outside my loop
echo '<pre>';print_r(wp_get_attachment_image_src ( $id, 'thumbnail' )); echo'</pre>';
```

The result shows the first index of the array (the src URL) to be:

`http://localhost/test1/wp-content/uploads/sites/0/2013/03/front-150x150.png`

Visiting this URL results in a 500 error on my setup, because the real URL is :

`http://localhost/test1/wp-content/uploads/sites/10/2013/03/front-150x150.png`

Why would WordPress drop a number (in case you missed it the leading **1** from the first number after `/sites/` from the image's URL when returning it via `wp_get_attachment_image_src` ?  Similarly echoing `wp_get_attachment_image()` also shows a broken image (with the same incorrect source URL).

**.HTACCESS**

```
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]

# add a trailing slash to /wp-admin
RewriteRule ^([_0-9a-zA-Z-]+/)?wp-admin$ $1wp-admin/ [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteRule ^ - [L]
RewriteRule ^([_0-9a-zA-Z-]+/)?(wp-(content|admin|includes).*) $2 [L]
RewriteRule ^([_0-9a-zA-Z-]+/)?(.*\.php)$ $2 [L]
RewriteRule . index.php [L]
</IfModule>

# END WordPress
```

Comment: Is there something wonky in your `.htaccess` file?  Mine has this in it for the `/files/*`: `RewriteRule ^([_0-9a-zA-Z-]+/)?files/(.+) wp-includes/ms-files.php?file=$2 [L]`

Comment: Actually, something else seems to be happening here.  My multisite media URLs all look like `http://example.com/files/10/2013/03/file.ext` .  Yours seem to have `wp-content/uploads` inserted in front of the `/files` part, which I don't think is right.  Check your site's settings -- `/wp-admin/network/site-settings.php?id=10` -- and have a look at `Upload Path` (mine is `wp-content/blogs.dir/10/files`) and `Fileupload Url` (mine is `http://example.com/sitename/files`).

Comment: @Pat J, that's normal for the new multisite installs, to skip the `ms-files.php` handling (http://core.trac.wordpress.org/ticket/19235)

Comment: Thanks Pat. I just posted my .htaccess though it looks like the one provided to me by the network setup.  I also don't think there is an input for changing your upload path anymore (or I am not seeing it).

Comment: @birgire, I had no idea.  I'm running 3.5.1 but it's on a system that's been continuously upgraded since 3.0(ish).

Comment: So far I have tracked the problem down to `get_current_blog_id` for some reason it appears to be returning the blog ID as 0 when the blog id should be 10.

Comment: You could try to see what `<?php print_r(wp_upload_dir());?> `gives you.

Comment: `get_current_blog_id` [ain't working](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/94060/12615) for me (only tested in localhost) when using Subdirectories instead of Subdomains. Could all commenteers confirm that?

Comment: seems to be working for me with `define( 'SUBDOMAIN_INSTALL', false );` (originally 3.? install but updated to 3.5.1)

Comment: Works for me too.  Found the problem in that Woothemes put in some ridiculous code in the header.php `$GLOBALS[blog_id] = get_option('woo_blog_id');` that was overwriting the global blog id!

Comment: ok interesting, do you know why they do it like this??

Comment: Not at all.  I am not even 100% sure it was them, as I inherited this project from some unknown person, who had coded away in the /Object theme folder before I moved everything to a child theme.

Comment: @brasofilo -- `get_current_blog_id()` is working for me, same settings as @birgire (v. 3.0 updated to 3.5.1).

Comment: @PatJ & birgire, thx for the follow up.

Answer (score 2):

I found this stray code in the `header.php`

```
$GLOBALS[blog_id] = get_option('woo_blog_id');
```

This wiped out the global variable that `get_current_blog_id()` relies on to get the site id in multisite.  This is then used by `wp_get_attachment_url()` to build the appropriate URL.

Because I was getting an incorrect site id, my attachment URLs were coming out wrong.